# Are the given events $f<0$ and $g<0$ are independent of each other?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have the two functions $f$ and $g$ for the variable **$x\in(0,a)$ where $a\to\infty$** (uniform distribution)

$$f=\sin(\frac{2\pi}7)-\sin (2\pi x)$$
$$g=\cos(2\pi x-x)\,\cos(x)$$

> $f$ **is periodic**; suppose that we can calculate the probability that this function is negative, say $P(f<0)=p_1$.

> $g$ is **not periodic**; we can calculate the probability that this function is negative, since the arguments of $\cos$ are incommensurate, $P(g<0)=p_2=\frac 12$.

**My Question**

> Can we consider  the events of negativity of $f$ and $g$  as **independent events**?

Answer (score 1):

For two random events $A$ and $B$ to be independent, their joint probability distribution must be equal to the product of their marginal distributions, i.e.

$P(A \land B) = P(A) P(B)$

Or, equivalently, conditioning on one event doesn't change the distribution of the other, i.e.

$P(A | B) = P(A)$

So in this case, you're asking whether $P(g(X) < 0 | f(X) < 0) = P(g(X) < 0)$, with $X \sim Unif(0, a)$, or at least whether that holds approximately in a way that converges to equality as $a$ goes to infinity.

To answer it properly I think you have to delve into a little bit of measure theory, since you're essentially trying to ask whether the set $\{x : g(x) < 0\}$ takes up proportionally as much space within the set $\{x : f(x) < 0\}$ as it does the positive real line.

Intuitively, though, I think the answer is yes - even comparing $f(x)$ and $\hat{g}(x) = \cos((2 \pi - 1) x)$, the fact that their periods don't line up means that over a large enough interval knowing whether one of them is negative isn't going to give any information about whether the other is or not, so when you then multiply $\hat{g}$ with a function that has yet another incompatible period, any relationship between them should be just about destroyed.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I thought maybe there is a simpler way to know that. For example, it is clear that the arguments of the functions $f$ and $g$ are incommensurate, then, is not this enough to conclude that for large values of $x$, they bahave independently?

Comment: Broadly, yes, and that's what I'm trying to claim. In any small range of $x$ they're probably not completely independent - for example, between x = 1000 and x = 1001 the two events are mutually exclusive, as you can see on [this plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7By+%3D+sin%282+pi+%2F+7%29+-+sin%282+pi+x%29%2C+y+%3D+cos%28%282+pi+-+1%29+x%29+cos%28x%29%7D%2C+1000+%3C+x+%3C+1001). It's more about proving that once the whole interval is wide enough the lack of common period gives them a chance to cross paths arbitrarily many times.